# How does binary format differentiate between actual trailing zeros and empty padding?

Tags: encoding, binary, bmp

How can everyone be so sure that "36 00 00 00" means actually 0x36 and not 0x36000000?

[image]

I know this is basic, I've just started learning and really don't see a marker for the length of the variable or is there a difference between zeros and just empty space in padding?

Comment: It's little endian, those zeroes are leading zeroes that don't affect the value

Comment: what does that mean for writing direct hex values to file? is the order actually reversed? since how can leading zeros be at the end

Comment: Well "reversed" is still ambiguous because there is no inherent order. To be clear, the least significant byte is put at the lowest address. As it happens (not a coincidence, of course) that is the same order in which some popular architectures store their integers.